# Device differences Xaml setting on Idiom

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to used OnIdiom, I am setting width and height to button however if I display the button on tablet and on phone it is the same. Can you please advise what am I doing wrong?

```
<Button  
        x:Name="ScanButton"  Padding="0"
        VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Button.Style>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Style" Tablet="{StaticResource PrimaryButtonStyleTablet}" Phone="{StaticResource PrimaryButtonStylePhone}"></OnIdiom>
        </Button.Style>
      </Button>     

<Style x:Key="PrimaryButtonStylePhone" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonColor}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTintColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="25"/>
                  <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="33"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="PrimaryButtonStyleTablet" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonColor}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTintColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="25"/>
              <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="390"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="33"/>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `OnIdiom` inside the **Setter.Value**.

For example, modify code of `Style` as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="PrimaryButtonStyle"
        TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Phone="{DynamicResource phoneDynamicResource}"
                        Tablet="{DynamicResource tableDynamicResource}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextColor">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Phone="Blue" Tablet="Green"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Phone="20" Tablet="20"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Phone="25" Tablet="25" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Phone="200" Tablet="390" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom  Phone="33" Tablet="33" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And used for `Button`:

```
<Button x:Name="ScanButton"
        Padding="0"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        Text="Button"
        Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButtonStyle}"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
</Button>
```

Comment: @Rntakokoi But it works in my local site. Maybe there are somewhere wrong in the project. You could share a sample project link without actual data here, I will check that.

Comment: <OnIdiom Phone="{DynamicResource phoneDynamicResource}"
                        Tablet="{DynamicResource tableDynamicResource}"/> where do I set this?

Comment: @Rntakokoi Here is the `DynamicResource` the same with your shared code.If need to use, you could refer to here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic However, not undestanding why here need to use this.

Comment: it works now, I guess it didn't save. I am using VS Mac and sometimes is a bit dodgy..sorry for confusion

Comment: @Rntakokoi That's great! Glad it be helpful.